# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'notes', how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql

I have used react hook here,ani I keep getting this error.

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'notes'. Either include
>   it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update
>   'setNotes(n => ...)' if you only need 'notes' in the 'setNotes' call 
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
    const createNoteListner = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const oldnotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id);
          const updatedNotes = [...oldnotes, newNote];
          return updatedNotes;
        });
        setNote("");
      }
    });
    const deleteNoteListner = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onDeleteNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const deleteNote = noteData.value.data.onDeleteNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const updatedNotes = prevNotes.filter(
            note => note.id !== deleteNote.id
          );
          return updatedNotes;
        });
      }
    });
    const updateNoteListner = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onUpdateNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const updatedNote = noteData.value.data.onUpdateNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const index = prevNotes.findIndex(note => note.id === updateNote.id);

          const updatedNotes = [
            ...notes.slice(0, index),
            updatedNote,
            ...notes.slice(index + 1)
          ];

          return updatedNotes;
        });
        setNote("");
        setId("");
      }
    });
    return () => {
      createNoteListner.unsubscribe();
      deleteNoteListner.unsubscribe();
      updateNoteListner.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: in `updateNoteListner` you refers to `notes` instead of `prevNotes`. believe there is no special reason, just a typo

Answer (score 1):

In your code in the end of your code there is a `}, [])`

If you want your `useEffect` update by changing some props or state you can mention it in that array for example  `}, [props.sth])` and if you want your `useEffect` call every time you need to remove that empty array and your code will end like :  `})`

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `notes` in the dependencies of your effect
If not , changes will not be reflected.

```
...

  return() =>{
      createNoteListner.unsubscribe();
      deleteNoteListner.unsubscribe();
      updateNoteListner.unsubscribe();
  }
}, [notes])
```